# How to change the default application for .ipynb files in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, ubuntu-18.04, jupyter-lab

In Ubuntu 18.04, the text editor is the default application to open the ipynb files, I want to change it to jupyter-lab or jupyter-notebook.

I also tried to change the file default application but the option for jupyter-lab or jupyter-notebook was not there.

Comment: @unutbu how did you find the related question so quickly?

Comment: I googled "Ubuntu double-click ipynb".

Answer (score -2):

You can change that by right-clicking and then going to "Properites" and then go to "Open with" tab and then select your default option to open with.

For further reference, please visit the official [Ubuntu documentation
link](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/files-open.html.en).

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't show the option of jupyter-lab or jupyter-notebook

Comment: Run jupyter notebook. do pwd(gives you the working directory). so that you will you can get the location of the installation and point the default application to the installation folder.

Comment: @DareDevil7 Thanks, but this is not working - even if you get the filapath to jupyter notebook, the "Properties" menu doesn't allow you to choose a filepath, just installed applications. If you know that this method is working for sure, please provide step by step instructions. Thanks