# Ubuntu: Double click ipynb file to open with jupyter-lab

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter-lab

## Existing questions and tests

### Windows or Mac specific questions

There are several questions that address this question for these operating systems. For example, [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59412154/how-to-associate-ipynb-files-with-jupyter-lab-from-anaconda-on-windows-10), [windows mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30953227/double-click-to-open-an-ipython-notebook), and [mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16158893/open-an-ipython-notebook-via-double-click-on-osx).

### Ubuntu

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55314631/how-to-change-the-default-application-for-ipynb-files-in-ubuntu-18-04) focusses on Ubuntu, however, marked duplicate and there is no clear answer.

### Test 1

I tested `nbopen`, but it opens the `.ipynb` file using `jupyter-notebook` and not `jupyterlab`

### Test 2

As suggested in comments, I tried to navigate to the `open with` options of a `.ipynb` file. However, it does not contain `jupyter-lab`.

Screenshot shown here[image: here]

## Question

For Ubuntu, how to open a `.ipynb` file using `jupyterlab` directly through a double click?

### System specifications

Mint 20.1 and anaconda (navigator 2.0.1)

Answer (score -1):

Try right-click on an `.ipynb` file, then `open with other application`, then click the `View All Applications` and navigate to `jupyterlab`, selecting it should make it the default application allowing you to double click and open automatically in jupyterlab in the future.

Comment: I tried that, however, there is no `jupyterlab' option available.

Comment: Do you have jupyterlab installed? i.e. can you, yourself navigate to the application via Ubuntu applications, not from command line?

Comment: No. The application menu does not contain the Jupyter Lab option.